# Extension showing html on frontend

Tags: typo3, fluid-layout, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am new to Typo3 development. I am using Typo3 version 6.2.0. I have created a custom extension using extension buider. Its working is basic and  just register two values name and id.

Extension is showing a link to new registration but after that its is showing fluid+html tags on the page instead of showing rendered output(textbox and form).

Please help me solving this problem.

```
 <form name="newTest" action="index.php?id=24&amp;tx_tl1_t...<form name="newTest" action="index.php?id=24&amp;tx_tl1_tl2%5Baction%5D=create&amp;tx_tl1_tl2%5Bcontroller%5D=Test&amp;cHash=b3050554aab196ddb3773dbb3eefda3c" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tl1_tl2[__referrer][@extension]" value="Tl1" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tl1_tl2[__referrer][@vendor]" value="Cts" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tl1_tl2[__referrer][@controller]" value="Test" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tl1_tl2[__referrer][@action]" value="new" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tl1_tl2[__referrer][arguments]" value="YToyOntzOjY6ImFjdGlvbiI7czozOiJuZXciO3M6MTA6ImNvbnRyb2xsZXIiO3M6NDoiVGVzdCI7fQ==a98b3f0778be75a7fc4b7f2fbe9f541196f8c763" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_tl1_tl2[__trustedProperties]" value="a:1:{s:7:&quot;newTest&quot;;a:1:{s:8:&quot;username&quot;;i:1;}}18e3421cc9d103c83147f40c4a539581aef5788e" />
Username

<input type="text" name="tx_tl1_tl2[newTest][username]" />
<input type="submit" name="" value="Create new" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should probably show a little code, like what's generating the (encoded?) tags, and perhaps a screen capture of what is being displayed to help us visualize it.

Comment: I have added the code that is shown on frontend(page) after clikcing new register link.The fluid tags have been rendered to html but instead of showing textboxes it is just showing this code.

Comment: Your sample code has two opening form tags. Are you sure that your html code is valid?

Comment: this code is displaying on the view page after rendering....I have not wrote it by myself.